# Compiling asmFish on macOS

Tags: engines, software, programming, linux, macos

I have been able to make a custom build of asmFish on Linux. However, I have been unable to do so on macOS. I've seen a Mac version of the FASM compiler on the Internet.  But when I tried using it for building it, it didn't generate a binary that could be run.

I am running the latest macOS at time of writing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is too hard-core for this forum. Try talkchess or ASM's github page?

Answer (score 1):

asmFish is NOT the same engine as Stockfish, so the answer by Dave is wrong. The difference is that asmFish is written in x86 Assembly (~20% faster), while Stockfish in C++.

[Here](https://github.com/lantonov/asmFish/issues/214) is an issue I opened to test basically the time fasmg did to compile asmFish. It was closed, however, because the latest fasmg version fails to compile asmFish. The latest working version is [this one](https://github.com/lantonov/asmFish/files/2418012/fasmg.zip).

You can download the version you want, but this is not necessary. You just need to open a command line and clone the repository:

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/lantonov/asmFish.git
```

Then, run `cd asmFish` to enter the directory and `make.bat` to compile.

For what it's worth:

- There are already MacOS binaries in the main repository. They are in the `MacOS_binaries` folder.
- There is also an archive of the executables in the executables branch, which is rarely updated.
- You can directly compile asmFish from MacOS from the command line just having the whole `x86` folder and the `fasmg` file:

  ```
   fasmg "x86\fish.asm" "asmFishX_type" -e 1000 -i "VERSION_OS='X'" -i "PEDANTIC = 1" -i "VERSION_POST = 'version'"
  ```

Replace `type` and `version` with the version post you want (`base`, `popcnt`, `bmi1` and `bmi2`)

Answer (score 0):

You can download Stockfish for OS X already built.  https://stockfishchess.org/

Comment: I think it does.  A complied binary of asmFish = Stockfish.  If the user is asking a computer programming question then yes, as mentioned by Student T above, this is the wrong forum.

Comment: No, asmFish is absolutely not the same as Stockfish. asmFish is a reimplementation of Stockfish's algorithms in x86 assembly. It has an entirely different codebase ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/lantonov/asmFish)). Downloading a build of SF will not get you a build of asmFish.